# when login from ionic app to dashboard the menu button showing as a back button

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/dashboard/home';
import { Signup } from '../../commen/signup/signup';
import { Forgot } from '../../commen/forgot/forgot';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service'
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';








@Component({
  selector: 'page-Login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class Login {
  forgot:any;
  
  spinnerLoad: boolean = false;
  msg:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private authservice: AuthService,public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.forgot=Forgot;
  
  
  }

  Submitlogin(value: any) {
    
    if(value.email){
    this.spinnerLoad = true;
  
    let email = value.email;
    let pass = value.password;
    
    this.authservice.login(email, pass).subscribe((result) => {
      this.spinnerLoad = false;
      if (result)
        if (result.status) {
          localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(result.data));
          this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
        } else {
          const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: 'Invalid credentials',
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'bottom'
          });
          toast.present();
        
          this.spinnerLoad = false;
          
          

        }
    }, error => {
      this.spinnerLoad = true;
      
    });
  }

  }
  onSignup() {
  
    this.navCtrl.push(Signup);
  }
  facebookLogin(){
    // alert('hello')
    // window.location.href = 'http://d4v.nextfellow.com/login/facebook';
  }
}
```

```html
<form ngsubmit="formvalue()">
<ionic-input type="text"  placeholder="email example"></ionic-input>
<ionic-input type="text"  placeholder="password"></ionic-input>
    
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" type="submit"   block>Login</button>
      </ion-col>
      </form
```

html is my dummy code once i validate form and route to dashboard on the header side of the menu button showing as a back button but it should be menu right please give me the solution for this also i have dashboard component
am working on ionic 3 its ....................................................

Comment: Just voted to close really the question is just hard to understand.  Please separate the thoughts into sentences and sprinkle some punctuation in there :)  Also, maybe include some screenshots to make it easier to explain the problem since it sounds like it can be quickly explained visually.  Also be sure the question hasn't been previously answered https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ionic+menu+back+button

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);` instead of `this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);`

Comment: Yeap, this is how it should be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a another way to do it. Do the following in  `HomePage.ts`

```
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.viewCtrl.showBackButton(false);
}
```